# Are there any demons of CR 1/2?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

[Summon Lesser Demons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/summon-lesser-demons) will summon for the caster a number of demons based on a d6 roll; either 2 CR 1 (or less) demons, four CR 1/2 (or less), or eight CR 1/4 (or less).

CR 1 demons include [Quasits](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/quasit) and [Maw Demons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/maw-demon); CR 1/4 gives us the [Dretch](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/dretch) (and [Manes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/manes) are available at CR 1/8). However, I could not find any CR 1/2 demons that the middle result might summon. Searching D&D Beyond for [creatures tagged "demon"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-search=&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=&filter-tags=59&sort=cr) didn't turn up any demon of CR 1/2.

Does the published material actually include any such demons that this spell result could summon, or is the unlucky caster stuck with getting a measly four Dretches or Manes?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## The [Cackler](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/cackler)

Apparently there were none until the Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica showed up.The Cackler is the only one dndbeyond.com that fits the CR 1/2 criteria.

To find this, my [filter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-type=9&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=4&filter-cr-max=4&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=&filter-sub-types=9) looked at Fiends->Demon Subtype->CR 1/2-1/2.

Comment: Ah, good spot. The site search seems to have some sort of indexing error which stops the Cackler showing up if you actually filter for demons.

Comment: @Carcer Really? I used the [filter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-type=9&filter-search=&filter-cr-min=4&filter-cr-max=4&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=&filter-sub-types=9) to find it.

Comment: FWIW, I was also able to confirm through a third party source (that I'm not linking here for obvious reasons) that the Cackler is the only 5e Demon of CR1/2. So the creature might not be tagged correctly in DNDBeyond.

Comment: Oooh, right, there's an actual "subtype" field as well! I got to "tag" in the filter list, saw "angel" as an example thereof, and assumed that "demon" tag would therefore find me all the demons. And it did find almost all of them...

Comment: @Xirema yeah, looks like it's missing the "demon" tag, though it does correctly list with the "demon" subtype.

Comment: Reported the bug: https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/d-d-beyond-general/bugs-support/32909-cackler-seems-to-have-demon-subtype-but-not-tag

Comment: It's fixed now.